# Why i don't get the console.log in JS

Tags: javascript, object

new in the environment. I made an Object constructor to build cars: here's my code :

```js
function Car(make, model, year) {

  this.make = make;

  this.model = model;

  this.year = year;

}

var $1stCar = Car("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2015);

var $2ndCar = Car("Porsche", "911", 2018);

var $3rdCar = Car("Lamborghini", "Huracan", 2019);

var $4rdCar = Car("Mono", "Bach", 2020);

var $5thCar = Car("Bugatti", "Chiron Super Sport 300", 2022);

var $6thCar = Car("Bugatti", "SuperBuq - 1st", 2025);

var $7thCar = Car("Tesla", "Rod-X", 2035);

console.log($1stCar);
```

i get 'undefined'. to me the variable is valid since it has an dollars sign in the beginning. Any one has tips? :)

Happy coding!

Comment: You are missing the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (it is even the same example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the "new" keyword:

```
let firstCar =  new Car ("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2015);
```

instead of

```
var $1stCar = Car ("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2015);
```

And $ as variable prefix is typically used with PHP but not in JS - it will work but it´s not common.

Comment: No. `$` is a perfectly valid symbol to use in a JS variable name. "at least nobody uses that kind of notation" — Ever heard of jQuery?

Comment: It *is* perfectly valid (and not uncommon), but it typically has meaning in an application, and without an actual reason, I wouldn't use it for general variables.

Comment: @MichaelFürst ... It's been a dominant JS thing for years and years; maybe you've never seen jQuery.

Comment: Yeah right - now when I think back it was uses as an alias for jquery() itself. However naming all variables with a $ prefix is quite seldom at this times.

Comment: @MichaelFürst The issue isn't with frequency/commonality, but with the statement that it's "not supported".

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `new` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) to create an instance.

```js
function Car(make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

let $1stCar = new Car("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2015);

console.log($1stCar);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add *new* before using your constructor.

```js
function Car (make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

let $1stCar = new Car ("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2015);

console.log ($1stCar);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q. Why it is showing Undefined?**

- Here you are invoking this function as a regular function without using the new operator. The Regular Function needs an explicit return
  operator, otherwise it will give you an undefined value.

Difference Between Regular And Constructor Function

**Regular Function:**

```
function example(value){
    return value
}
```

**Invoking Regular Function and storing the return value to a variable:**

```
let store = example("Hello!")
```

**Constructor Function:**

```
function Example(name){
    this.name = name
}
```

**Invoking Constructor Function with the new operator:**

`let Store = new Example("Hello")` // This will return a new object and assign the newly created object to the Store Variable.

When you are creating Objects using Constructor function then you need to invoke it with a new operator so that it will return an object.